# Firemonkey to iPhone

Tags: iphone, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Here I have my Windows laptop with Delphi XE2 and Firemonkey.

I've written a little Firemokey `hello world` app.
In my hand I have my new iPhone 4S that I just brought home.

What are the steps to get my Firemonkey app onto my iPhone?

Comment: There must be something in the documentation, surely?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a Mac and a membership in one of several [Apple developer Programs](http://developer.apple.com/)

You can find prerequisites [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites)

[edit] Steps are described [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_a_FireMonkey_Application#iOS_Workflow)

Answer (score 6):

Stefaan Lesage has a [video tutorial](http://www.devia.be/news/article/configuring-delphi-xe2-and-your-mac-to-develop-test-and-deploy-ios-apps/) that walks you through the steps to develop for and deploy to iOS.

Comment: I hope the Video Tutorials are useful enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Tim Anderson's Blog is another good resource.](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/4841-hands-on-with-delphi-xe2-for-apple-ios.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iPhone 4S with iOS 5 it is only compatible with XCode 4.2 which only runs on OSX Lion. I believe that FireMonkey and the Free Pascal modules are not yet compatible with Lion and XCode 4.2. I think I may have seen on a blog that there is a beta version of FireMonkey around which will work on Lion with XCode 4.2

I understand you will need XCode 3.2.6 on Snow Leopard which will allow you to deploy your application to an iPhone running iOS 4 if you sign up, and pay, to join one of the iOS development programs ($99).

Once you've done that there are some good tutorials on the Embarcadero web site as well as YouTube.

I've written an iOS app that runs in the simulator but I have an iPhone with iOS 5 so stuck at thsi moment as I cannot deploy to the phone. Everything else works well though and FireMonkey appears to be pretty good if you have a Delphi background and I'm sure it will get better.

Comment: disregarding the "firemonkey only runs on 3.2.6" aspect, it's not true that you need lion to develop for IOS 5.0 . I run IOS 4.2 on Snow Leopard 10.6.8, and it supports IOS 5.0 just fine. I have built apps and installed them on an Ipod touch running 5.0, as well as using the IOS simulator under 5.0 on Snow Leopard, and an onto an Iphone 4.2 and ipad running IOS 4.2,  to be fair however, I don't use fireMonkey, and i have not tried installing on a IOS4s device. keen to check out fireMonkey however, as delphi was my tool of trade for many years.